# Why does "Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"" keep popping up?

Tags: r, r-markdown

[I can't get rid of this error. Please help!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT6qY.png)

Comment: I guess you want `%>%` and not `%in%`.

Comment: Images are not a good way to share your code or data. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).